# Build multiple apk with a flavor and multiple config

Tags: android, gradle, android-build-flavors

I know it's possible to have multiple flavor with configuration for each of them. but i have a big list of configuration (about 15) and i don't want to define 15 flavor in build configuration. I'm looking for some approach base on looping on gradle build task with changing configuration of flavor or any similar approach that don't need to define exactly all flavor by hand.

any suggestions ?

**Updated :**

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
  Properties props = new Properties()
  props.load(new FileInputStream(file('build.properties')))
  compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
  buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    resConfigs "en"

    versionCode props['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger()
    versionName props['VERSION_NAME']
    buildConfigField('boolean', 'DEBUG_MODE', "false")
    buildConfigField('String', 'DEBUG_VERSION', props['EMPTY_STRING'])

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      shrinkResources true
      proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }

  sourceSets {
    sd_debug {
      assets {
        srcDirs('src/sd_debug/assets')
      }
      java {
        srcDirs('src/sd_debug/java')
      }
      res {
        srcDirs('src/sd_debug/res')
      }
    }

    sp_debug {
      assets {
        srcDirs('src/sd_debug/assets')
      }
      java {
        srcDirs('src/sd_debug/java')
      }
      res {
        srcDirs('src/sd_debug/res')
      }
    }

    sd_debug_devpackage {
      assets {
        srcDirs('src/sd_debug/assets')
      }
      java {
        srcDirs('src/sd_debug/java')
      }
      res {
        srcDirs('src/sd_debug/res')
      }
    }

    sp_prod {
      assets {
        srcDirs('src/main/assets')
      }
      java {
        srcDirs('src/sp_prod/java')
      }
      res {
        srcDirs('src/sp_prod/res')
      }
    }
  }

  productFlavors {
    // develop flavor
    sd_debug {
      buildConfigField 'String', 'DEBUG_VERSION', props['DEBUG_VERSION']
      buildConfigField 'boolean', 'DEBUG_MODE', "true"
      buildConfigField 'Integer', 'HOST_ID', "90"
    }
    sp_debug {
      buildConfigField 'String', 'DEBUG_VERSION', props['DEBUG_VERSION']
      buildConfigField 'boolean', 'DEBUG_MODE', "true"
      buildConfigField 'Integer', 'HOST_ID', "1"
    }
    sd_debug_devpackage {
      buildConfigField 'String', 'DEBUG_VERSION', props['DEBUG_VERSION']
      buildConfigField 'boolean', 'DEBUG_MODE', "true"
      buildConfigField 'Integer', 'HOST_ID', "91"
    }

    sp_prod {
      buildConfigField 'boolean', 'DEBUG_MODE', "false"
      buildConfigField 'Integer', 'HOST_ID', "1"
    }
  }

  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude '.readme'
  }

  dexOptions {
    jumboMode = true
  }
}


dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

  compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
  compile "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
  compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"

  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$rootProject.playServiceVersion"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$rootProject.playServiceVersion"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$rootProject.playServiceVersion"
  compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$rootProject.okhttpVersion"
  compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:$rootProject.gsonVersion"
  compile "com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:$rootProject.ormliteVersion"
  compile "com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:$rootProject.ormliteVersion"
  compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$rootProject.butterknifeVersion"
  compile "me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:$rootProject.zbarVersion"
  compile "de.greenrobot:eventbus:$rootProject.eventbusVersion"
  //  compile "io.reactivex:rxjava:$rootProject.rxjavaVersion"
  //  compile "io.reactivex:rxandroid:$rootProject.rxjavaVersion"
  compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
  annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.daggerVersion"


  // Dependencies for local unit tests
  testCompile "junit:junit:$rootProject.ext.junitVersion"
  testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:$rootProject.ext.mockitoVersion"
  testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:$rootProject.ext.hamcrestVersion"
  testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:$rootProject.ext.powerMockito"
  testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:$rootProject.ext.powerMockito"

  // Android Testing Support Library's runner and rules
  androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:runner:$rootProject.ext.runnerVersion"
  androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:rules:$rootProject.ext.rulesVersion"

  // Espresso UI Testing dependencies.
  androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
  androidTestCompile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
  androidTestCompile "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
  androidTestCompile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"

  androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion"
  androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion"
  androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion"
}
```

each flavor must be build with an api key, and i have 15 api keys.

Comment: You can use the full featureset of Groovy with its expressiveness and compactness and dynamicness. Isn't that enough to define your flavors in a compact way that does not need much duplication? I don't do Android development, so show me your build with 2 or 3 flavors and I might tell you how to make it more concise.

Comment: @Vampire thank you, please show your solution .

Comment: I don't see anywhere `api` or `key`. Which part is the one that you need 15 times with which parts different for the 15 instances?

Comment: Of course, Suppose a custom list of string by your. Don't matter i just want see sulotion

Comment: Well, how should I be able to provide a solution if you don't give proper input? If you cannot or don't want to answer my question, I cannot help you and honestly, with your tone I start loosing interest to invest my precious time to solve your problems.

Comment: I don't know how to define task so how can i provide proper input ? You can suppose host_id is my interested config with list of 15 diffrent number 1 to 15 for example. I really interest to see your soloution brother, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this solve your problem?

```
[
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '7',
    '8',
    '9',
    '10',
    '11',
    '12',
    '13',
    '14',
    '15'
].each { hostId ->
    sourceSets {
        "sp_prod_$hostId" {
            assets {
                srcDirs('src/main/assets')
            }
            java {
                srcDirs('src/sp_prod/java')
            }
            res {
                srcDirs('src/sp_prod/res')
            }
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        "sp_prod_$hostId" {
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'DEBUG_MODE', "false"
            buildConfigField 'Integer', 'HOST_ID', hostId
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got your idea , but it's better to have one task for build all configuration with one command. Your code generate 15 build variant by code . it's great but i will be happy if can do it with one flavor.

Comment: Just make one task that depends on the 15 individual tasks, then you can at any time just build one flavor, but at the same time have one task that builds them all. What is the task that needs to be called per flavor?

Comment: It's assembleRealese task that build apk.

Comment: Well, then inside the `each` closure something like `assembleRelease.dependsOn "assembleSp_prod_${hostId}Release"` or how the task is named per flavor should do to build all the flavors when `assembleRelease` is called. But doesn't `assemble` depend on all flavor / buildType combinations anyway?